# Camel AMQP autoAck failed to resolve an endpoint

Tags: azure, apache-camel, amqp, azureservicebus

I am trying to set autoAck to false while reading from azure service bus queue, which I am connecting using amqp. Below is the code.

```
from("amqp:queue:testqueue?autoAck=false&concurrentConsumers=1")
```

But I am getting an error msg:

```
Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[amqp:queue:testqueue?autoAck=false&concu... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: amqp://queue:testqueue?autoAck=false&concurrentConsumers=1 due to: Failed to resolve endpoint: amqp://queue:testqueue?autoAck=false&concurrentConsumers=1 due to: There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{autoAck=false}]
```

I am trying to process the messages from the service bus queue but don't want them to be removed till the time processing is not complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer, in order to remove the messages from the queue only when a consumer has accepted the message and acknowledged that it was successfully processed, you need to add "acknowledgementModeName" to the route

```
from("amqp:queue:testqueue?acknowledgementModeName=CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE&concurrentConsumers=1")
```

For more clarification visit this page http://camel.apache.org/jms.html